# Create Gridview Template field dynamically with sorting function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hope you can help me with this

I need to create a page that will display gridview based on user wants (programmatic ally).Basically I have a list of columns then the user will choose for the list. I need also to have sorting function

I'm using a vb.net code

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare Headings and DataItems for each column and make them visible by default, then just after data bind make invisible to the chosen columns as below:

```
    gvData.DataSource = dataToLoad
    gvData.DataBind()

    Dim columnsIndex As List(Of Integer)
    columnsIndex = userChosedColumnsIndex
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    For Each counter In columnsIndex
        gvData.Columns(counter).Visible = False
    Next
```